# Rules for following a Vrat/Fast

Tags: fasting

What are the general rules for following a Vrat/Fast?

I know things like being nirjal or phalahar, praying with sincerity and staying up all night.

Is there anything else I am missing? Do Purascharan rules apply in any way? What if we cannot do a certain section of a vrat/fast due to an illness?